# Do I need to pass in all values of a tuple to index a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, hash, dictionary

Using Python, I have created a list that is indexed by a tuple:

```
return values[(a, b)]
```

However, sometimes I want to pass in `(a, _)` where I don't care what the value of `b` is and receive a list of all the possible indices.

Such as:

```
values[(dog, _)] => returns [(dog, Mike), (dog, Sam), (dog, Edward)]
```

Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the exact value of a key to index a dictionary.

To find multiple keys, you need to loop over them:

```
[k for k in my_dict if k[0] == dog]
```

Comment: Is there someway I can do I partial look-up (perhaps not using a dictionary)?

Comment: what do you mean by "partial" look up?  This answer looks at the first value in your tuple key.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of tuples then you can simply create a dictionary from the tuple list and utilize the first element as a dict key like so:

```
>>> import collections
>>> l = [('a', 'foo'), ('a', 'bar'), ('b', 'hello')]
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in l:
...   d[k].append(v)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['foo', 'bar'], 'b': ['hello']})
>>> d['a']
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't partially index a dictionary with tuple keys. You must use the same key to extract a data that you used to insert it.

However, an alternative approach would be to use nested dictionaries. That is, rather than indexing with a single tuple (`values[key1,key2]`), you'd index two times `values[key1][key2]`. If you only provide the first key, you'd get an inner dictionary containing the data.

Here's an example:

```
>>> d = {1: {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}, 2: {2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3}}
>>> d[1][1]
2
>>> d[1]
{1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
```

If you just want the values of one of the inner dictionaries, you can get it using the `values` method:

```
>>> d[1].values()
dict_values([2, 3, 4])
```

In Python 3, `dict.values` returns a "view" object, which is iterable. If you need a real list, just wrap the `values` call in the list constructor (just be aware the the order of the values is arbitrary):

```
>>> list(d[1].values())
[2, 3, 4]
```